# Have installed SVN. How to create repositories with trunk/tags/branches structure and start using with Tortoise SVN?

Tags: linux, svn, version-control, tortoisesvn, redhat

Previously I was using SVN which someone else installed on a Windows server, and we had Collabnet Subversion Edge to visually create, traverse and manage repositories, as well as create users, manage my user account, etc. from a web browser. In addition to this, I was actually working day-to-day using Tortoise SVN.

Now I'm trying to install SVN on a new Linux server (RHEL 5). I have finished the installation and I created a test repository:

```
svnadmin create /var/www/svn/test
```

And the test repository now looks like this on the server:

```
conf/
db/
format
hooks/
locks/
README.txt
```

What do I now need to do to create the standard branches/tags/trunk structure? I tried manually creating those directories using `mkdir` on the server but if I try to check out on my machine using Tortoise, I just get a hidden .svn directory and nothing else.

1. What am I missing or doing wrong?
2. Ultimately, I'd like to know if there is a visual interface like Collabnet's Subversion Edge which I can install and use on top of the Subversion which I've already installed? *Edit: Okay, I found the Linux versions, I will attempt to install with my limited knowledge.*

Comment: I would consider switching to [git](http://git-scm.com/) ....

Comment: BTW: You can create the folder structure manually as you did using mkdir. If you then do a svn checkout you will only expect to see the hidden .svn folder. This is normal. What else do you expect to see?

Comment: I actually expected to see those directories when I checked out.

Comment: Right. if you did a svn mkdir repo/project/trunk and you check out, you should see the trunk but under that just the .svn folder.. make reference to this post, it will help if you are setting up your structure manually http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760712/svn-how-do-i-create-a-subversion-repository-with-a-single-repository-multiple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I have a better understanding now. I used TortoiseSVN import to import a trunk/tags/branches directory structure into the repo.

Answer (score 1):

This shoud solve your problem:

```
mkdir /tmp/svn-structure   

mkdir /tmp/svn-structure/trunk branch tags

cd /path/to/the/repo/repoName

sudo svn import –m ‘template import’ /tmp/svn-structure/ http://ip/svn/repoName
```

I have compiled a document on how to install and configure subversion in linux environment here is the link

http://trainscm.blogspot.com/2015/03/installing-subversion-and-jenkins-in.html

hope it helps

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Hope that makes you happy :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try if you can  access your server ip for example http link (ip address of your svn server/svn/reposname) if you are able to access there seems to ok with your svn server data then use your client svn from another machine  to create new folder or to add file . The best way to check out whole things if you have written down your server svn web page link where you can manually create your repository or delete it . 
I would suggest not to use visual interface like collabnet's subversion edge it will create conflict with the current svn server if this help you out or not please reply

Comment: I am able to access the repository via HTTP yes. Why would Subversion Edge cause conflicts?

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to access Subversion Edge via HTTP then go to the web page.

By default it is:

```
   Address: http://localhost:3343/csvn
   Username: admin
   Password: admin
```

- Click on Repositories
- New Repository
- Enter your Reop name
- Check the box "" Create standard trunk/branches/tag structure'
- The click on create.

From there, download TortoiseSVN, and do a Repo Browser to connect to your new repository, then you can checkout.

Comment: I haven't got that far yet. I've installed but am currently unable to initialize Subversion Edge. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21909204/cannot-start-collabnet-subversion-edge

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can import your project work in your repository by svn client if you want you can add your project work inside trunk path only generally project should be kept inside trunk I hope I am able to solve your problem if you have any query do not hesitate to write